Sage Publications: APA style references
I'm preparing my manuscript for publication in Sage journal Music & Science. The journal requires APA style references. According to https://us.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/latex_frequently_asked_questions_10312017_.pdf, it should be working by just the added "sageapa" option. I've added the "sageapa" option in the beginning of the document using \documentclass[Afour,sageapa,times]{sagej} and at the end of the using \bibliographystyle{sageapa}, but the bibliography is not displayed. Changing \bibliographystyle{sageapa} to \bibliographystyle{sageh} will display the bibliography, but not in the correct APA style.
Have any of you observed something similar and can help? I'm using the sage template for overleaf.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the support of Sage journal?
